# 500.19 error in IIS7 and Windows 2008 with .NET 4.0

Tags: .net, windows, iis

We developed a .NET application to provide REST services. We are trying to deploy it in  IIS with the below server configuration:
IIS 7.0
SQL Server Express Edition 2008
Windows 2008 Server
.NET 4.0

We are getting the error as attached in the picture.

Please help This is driving us crazy.

THE ERROR MESSAGE IS

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal server Error
The requested page cannot be accesses because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
```

**

> Config Error:  The configuration
>   selection section 'standardEndpoints'
>   cannot be read because it is missing
>   section declaration

**

Comment: If you resolved this can you please post your answer.

Comment: Please post a snippet of the relevant section of the config file